# CKEditor dialog event after page/tab is opened

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dom-events

I'm making a custom plugin for CKEditor (4.4.7), that extends default image plugin. Inside the plugin I need an event like "when the page/tab becomes visible".

I know about CKEDITOR.dialog's event selectPage. It fires before the actual page (tab) is shown. What I need is an event, that would fire AFTER the page is selected AND visible. I went throughout the docs, but I didn't find anything. Are there any workarounds?

(Not sure if it's not just my ignorance, but I think that ckeditor lacks more events, than just this one.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my ugly workaround (inside dialog on show):

I get the DOM id of a child element of the tab(page) using

```
var childElementId = dialog.getContentElement('tabCkeditorId', 'childElementCkeditorId').domId;
```

Using jquery I find the closest element with attribute name="tab/page ckeditor id", because I haven't found any way the ckeditor could tell me the DOM id of a tab/page element directly.

```
var tabId = $("#"+childElementId).closest('[name="tabCkeditorId"]').attr('id');
```

Well and finally:

```
$('body').on('mouseover focusin keydown', '#'+tabId, function(event) {
    ...
});
```

It is not a truly on page "changed" event, but for my cause it works.

Answer (score 0):

By after page/tab opened, you mean the dialog box is opened, then you (as this is pretty old que) or anyone else trying to achieve this can use below,

```
editor.on( 'blur', function( dialogShowEvent ) {
      alert('Test');
    });
```

More can be found here - https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Blur-and-focus-fired-when-openingclosing-dialogs

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I don't think this is the solution. It wasn't about opening/closing a dialog. It was about switching between tabs (pages or whatever it is called) inside an opened dialog.

The reason I needed this, was that some component I used required to be visible when initialized. Otherwise it failed. That specific problem is probably not relevant today, but an event like tab/page switched (with -ed at the and, so it would fire after the page has changed and rendered) might still come in handy for other use cases.